# Accessing Atlas, individual, and embedded resources/images easily

Tags: c#, image

Basically, I have a bunch of images that I can combine into a single image(an atlas) or use individually. For testing/designing purposes, I would like to keep all the images separate but for release they should all be combine into the atlas(for non-embeddable compilers) or embedded.

e.g., suppose I have 100 sprites. I can create a single atlas for them, use them all individually unembedded, or embed the atlas, or embed all the image.

I'd like to start out with the individual+unembedded case for development then move to the embedded atlas case or embedded individual case(but I think this is probably not as good as the embedded atlas).

Is there an easy way to set this up in C# so the transition will be minimal?

The problem with the embedded atlas is that I would have to convert loading images(simple Image.FromFile into extracting images from the atlas).

Just curious what would be a good approach to remove the need for rewriting a lot of code in the future when the switch is made.

I could have something like Image.FromAtlas that essentially figures out the details(uses FromFile if we are in "development mode" or extracts the image from the atlas if in production... I think the embedded case would be rather trivial to implement).

What do you think? Thanks.